# flash drive at half capacity after 'dd image' format

Tags: dd

Yesterday, I wanted to try out Ubuntu, so i torrented Ubuntu 15.10 (I got the torrent file from ubuntu.com) and I used Rufus to format my 32gb flash drive. it then said that it had to "dd image format" it, I clicked okay and the format was done. However, when I booted from the flash drive, there were a lot of problems that I don't wish to go deeper here.

Anyway, later I torrented Ubuntu 12.04 and used Universal USB Installer (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), this time, everything worked just fine.

However, the first flash drive that i used (the one with Ubuntu 15.10) is now showing only about 14 gb in gparted and it shows as the only partition on it.

What should I do now?

Comment: Since, the image was dd'ed into the pendrive did you try this command: `sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXY`, then try formatting with GParted. Change XY to what your pendrive is.

Comment: I'm trying that right now, but it seems to be taking a long time, is this normal?

Comment: Its absolutely normal

Comment: i got this: 

root@ubuntu:~# sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd
dd: writing `/dev/sdd': No space left on device
3752+0 records in
3751+0 records out
15733161984 bytes (16 GB) copied, 2018.51 s, 7.8 MB/s

also, the drive still shows up as 14gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the ISO contained a partition table, which overwrote the one on the flash drive. To fix it, create a new partition table on the drive.

In GParted, you can find this in *Device* → *Create partition table*. Select a `msdos` partition table.

Make sure you are **really** operating on the correct drive, else you may end up with a non-booting computer.

Comment: I've tried this many times but the size remains at 14gb

Comment: @Thineswar Singaram - In parted you have to use mklabel command and then mkpart

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new to Ubuntu. Can you please explain that step-by-step?

Comment: @EdiD this is the exact same thing that is done by GParted when creating a new parttable and afterwards a new partition.

Comment: @the_Seppi - yes i know. I thought  that Thineswar Singaram created only new partition without new part. table

Comment: This is embarrassing, it turns out the flash drive was indeed a 16gb model (It was my friend's drive)
Thank you for all of your help and I am truly sorry about this.

Comment: So how did you 'repair' it in the end?